# is Material in flutter same as Material UI used in react?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, material-ui

I was wondering if the default Material used in Flutter is the same as [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui)
used in React. Are they following the same principle? Also, I would like to know some differences if there are any.

Comment: Both of them are implementations of the Material Design https://material.io . So yes, they follow the same guidelines